# Identifying freemason regalia from New York

Tags: new-york-state, fraternal-organization

[image]I just found out that my late grandfather was a Freemason.  I know he was with the grand lodge of New York.  I even have his membership number.  I am mostly curious about his regalia.  He has some very unique pins and some Templar stuff.

Can anyone give me insight into these items?

Comment: If your grandfather was born before 1921 our Privacy Policy in the [help/on-topic] will permit you to include his name and membership number.  That is not required but it may help you to attract a potential answerer to your question.

Comment: His name is Edward Welsh 1918-2006